Default Access when creating a SharePoint folder
When creating a folder in SharePoint, default access is assigned to groups Owners, Members, Visitors. You then have to manually remove them each time.
Sorry for low quality, was taken from a users screen. Essentially we created a folder and it automatically assigned access to the Owners which is correct, but beneath those two is 'Members' and 'Visitors'. Is there a way we can set this up so when creating a folder, it's exclusively the owners? (https://i.sstatic.net/4b71JyLj.png)

We'd like to do this so we don't have to keep removing the access each time.
Unfortunately I don't have full access and it's not clear if this is a modifiable thing or not. Played around in the settings but can't seem to spot anything.

Just an edit, in case anyone had the same question. Think I've just realised it's because it is inheriting permissions from top level. I assume there is no way around that without removing everyone's access.

If you are breaking default permissions each time you add a new folder to a SharePoint library, that is a symptom of poor planning and inappropriate information architecture.
The number one criterion when determining how to structure information architecture of a SharePoint farm is who needs what kind of access. Create sites for different audiences and set their permissions for the whole site.
As soon as you start breaking default permissions regularly, you need to review the site architecture. You may actually need a different site for the specific audience that needs special permissions.
Your license is not limiting the number of SharePoint sites you can create, and creating new sites is just a few clicks, so there is no reason why you shouldn't structure your content across multiple different sites, which are determined based on the permission boundaries.
Hub sites can easily provide the navigation components required for users to get easy access to their documents with minimal clicks. Links
and menus exist for a reason.
Having all content in a library with hundreds of sub folders with custom permissions is a maintenance nightmare and goes against the principles of the SharePoint architecture.
If you feel it's hard to do and hard to maintain, then the problem is not SharePoint, but the wrong use of Sharepoint.
